# IIS 7 app pool optimization

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, nginx

I have several sites running on win 2008 64bit/ IIS 7 with each sites go with a separate application pool (default settings).

The problem is that many of them, very simple and low traffic site, consume lots of memory(100mb - over 1 gb). Most of them are written in c# asp.net 4.0 managed code (linq to sql and entity framework 4-5.0).

say one app pool is at 90000 kb, if i run the web on browser, it could go up to more than 200000 kb. Is it normal ?

So what would i do to keep them[image] cool down without interrupting (much*) the performance ?

Should i lower the default recyling interval ?

Also, anyone know the best solution to monitor/trace memory leak that's easy to use.

Comment: Large memory usage may be related to either leaks, or an aggressive caching mechanism. Narrow your question down to a specific issue and you may receive more useful responses.